# Changing the functional/global environment in R

Tags: r, environment

Is there any way to change the set the working environment or workspace in R to a defined environment?  I'd like to call the variables in an environment without constantly referring to the environment.  I understand that the attach function can be used to access the variable in this manner, but any variables created don't get placed back in the attached environment.  The goal is to have all the functions take place in the *other* environment.

For example:

```
original.env <- .GlobalEnv
other.env <- new.env()  
other.env$A <- 12; other.env$B <- 1.5
set.env(other.env)  
C <- A + B          
set.env(original.env)   
other.env$C         
[1] 13.5
```

It's the step with `set.env` which I can't figure out if it exists, or there's some other trick to doing this.

The goal of this approach is to allow the same code to be used on different data sets with identical structures in several non-nested environments *without* constantly calling other environments with the `Environment$` prefix, which gets really verbose in many cases.

If the results can also be assigned back to the set environment (as in the global environment, everything has an implicit `.GlobalEnv$` in front of any variable) it would make it way easier to access and return multiple values from inside of a function.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for `eval` / `evalq`

From `help("evalq")`

> Evaluate an R expression in a specified environment.

Specifically, `evalq` noting

> The evalq form is equivalent to eval(quote(expr), ...). eval evaluates its first argument in the current scope before passing it to the evaluator: evalq avoids this.

```
# Therefore you want something like this
evalq(C <- A + B, envir = other.env)
```

If you want to wrap more than one expression use `{}` eg

```
evalq({C <-A + B
    d <-  5
       }, envir = other.env)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm pretty sure that eval/evalq is not what I'm looking for.  I would have to wrap basically every line of code (>100 lines) in the eval function, which seems needlessly verbose. 

Can you place multiple lines in the eval function? and then can you nest eval functions within a higher eval function?

I'd really prefer to just have a way to change where the gloabal environment is pointing.  It would be an immensely more efficient solution.

Comment: @WillL you  can place multiple 'lines' or expressions within {}. I'll edit the answer to show as such.

Answer (score 4):

How about using `with`?

```
original.env <- .GlobalEnv
other.env <- new.env() 
other.env$A <- 12; other.env$B <- 1.5
with(other.env, { C <- A + B ; FOO <- 'bar' })
other.env$C
[1] 13.5
other.env$FOO
[1] "bar"
```

Comment: I'd have the same concerns about this as I have with using the solution posted above.

Other than the order of the arguments in the function, what are the differences between "with" and "eval"?

Comment: I even included two statements to show you that it's possible. But generally speaking, if something you want to do seems overly hard in any programming language, it's often a strong indicator that the language designer(s) did not consider it important/advisable.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, please don't interpret my questions or counter-points as ingratitude.  Something can seem overly hard in language because the language developers didn't think it was advisable, or the programmer using the language doesn't know the "hooks" to make the code do what he wants in the "easy way".  I'm usually falling into the latter situation.  I'm starting to believe this is an example of the former situation, which is kinda disappointing, but oh well.

Comment: I'm still curious what the differences are between "with" and "evalq" if you have any insight.  Reading about these functions, it sounds like "evalq" can't save changes to the original data if the called environment is a frame, "within" can, and the documentation isn't clear to me for "with".

Comment: `eval`: Evaluate an R expression in a specified environment. `with`: Evaluate an R expression in an environment constructed from data, possibly modifying (a copy of) the original data. To be completely honest my example of using `with` for an empty env is not the greatest, since it doesn't provide data to construct an environment from.